# Mounting drives after removing Windows 10 and installing Kali Linux showing Error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, kali-linux

I had dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04..Anyway I formatted the partition that Windows 10 Installed On and Ubuntu too..After that I installed Kali Linux as Primay OS Without any dual boot or OS Inside it..So i noticed that it can't mount the partitions unless if i run this command in the terminal:

> mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda6 /media/drive

Like this..But if i run this command:

> mount -o -ro /dev/sda6 /media/drive

It will not mount..But Anyway in the first condition it need to run this command again after restart the Laptop..But in the second condition It returns this error:

> The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
>   Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Operation not permitted
>   The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>   Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>   read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

So How this Can be Fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, Use GParted then select the partition that you can't mount then right click and choose "Check" and It will find the problem and solve it automatically.